# Data attribute is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to set a data attribute `filtername` on an onClick which works fine.

```
$('#tag-group ul').append('<li><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" data-filtergroup="'+filterGroup+'" data-filtername="'+filterName+'"></i>'+text+'</li>');
```

It renders out on the screen ok as

```
<li><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" data-filtergroup="location" data-filtername="Melbourne"></i> Melbourne</li>
```

I am then trying to pick it up again on another onClick but it comes back as undefined. When I `console log $(this).text();` it works but when I console log `$(this).data('filtername');` it is undefined. Is the dom hiding it if it is generated by jQuery?

```
$(document).on('click','#sau-filter-tags ul li', function(event){
            var text = $(this).text();
            var filterName = $(this).data('filtername');
            console.log(filterName);  //Undefined
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `$(this)` to find out what _that_ even is? It’s not an element that has any `data` attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`filtername` is attribute of `i` tag in li.

You need to select `i` tag :

```
$(document).on('click', '#sau-filter-tags ul li i', function(event) {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var filterName = $(this).data('filtername');
  console.log(filterName); //Undefined
});
```

or you need to attach event to li and find I in `this` , Example:

`$(this).find('i').data('filtername')`

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting a data attribute on `i` tag. So you have to create an event upon `i`

```
$(document).on('click','#sau-filter-tags ul li i', function(event){
    var text = $(this).text();
    var filterName = $(this).data('filtername');
    console.log(filterName);  //Undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the attribute on your containing `<li>` rather than the `<i>` inside. Try the following:

```js
$('#sau-filter-tags li').on('click', function () {
    var i = $(this.firstElementChild)
    var text = i.text()
    var filterName = i.data('filtername')
    console.log(filterName) //=> 'Melbourne'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" data-filtergroup="location" data-filtername="Melbourne"></i> Melbourne</li>
```